# SQL - SELECT rows conditionally

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following is the criteria to select rows:

- for the same SysID, P2 would be preferred than P1.

I came up with this logic

```
    DECLARE @Products table
    (
        Id int,
        SysId varchar(100)          
    );

    INSERT INTO @Products
    SELECT Id, SysId FROM ProductMain
    WHERE ProductCode = 'P2'

    INSERT INTO @Products
    SELECT Id, SysId FROM ProductMain WHERE ProductCode = 'P1'
    AND SysId NOT IN (SELECT SysId FROM @subscription)

    --Result
    SELECT Id,SysId FROM @Products
```

*Sample Data*

```
Id  SysId  ProductCode
1   121    P1
2   121    P2
3   122    P1
4   123    P2
5   124    P1
6   124    P2
```

*Desired Output*

```
Id  SysId
2   121
3   122
4   123
6   124
```

I know there should be a better logic for this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any sample data of input and  final output

Comment: Just added input and desired output

Comment: I'd simply do a UNION on two queries - one where P2 exists and one where it doesn't (and use join instead of your subquery). Depending on data, it's likely to be fastest

Answer (score 1):

if P1, P2 is not the actual data, change the `ORDER BY` to `CASE WHEN ProductCode = 'P2' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT *, rn = row_number() over (partition by SysId ORDER BY ProductCode DESC)
   FROM   yourtable
) d
WHERE d.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
select * from tableA as a
where exists(select 1 from tablea as b where b.sysid = a.sysid and b.productcode = 'P2')  or 
exists(select 1 from tablea as b where b.sysid = a.sysid and b.productcode <> 'P2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering ProductCodes are assigned values like P1, P2, P3 and you want to get the Id with highest product code. In your case P2 is highest. You can use below given query

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK OVER(PARTITION BY SysId ORDER BY ProductCode DESC) As Rank
    FROM @Products
) AS ProductsNew
WHERE Rank = 1
```